# Setuid and setgid not working

Tags: linux, shell, c, setuid

I'm having a problem with setuid and setgid. I've written this C code:

```
int main() {
    setuid(0);
    setgid(0);
    system("/path/to/script.sh");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it using gcc:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Then I used `chmod +s`. In `script.sh` there's only the `id` command. Here are the permissions for the `test` executable:

```
-rwxr-sr-x  1 root   root   8464 mag 15 20:14 test
```

When I execute the program I get the following output:

```
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) gruppi=1000(user)
```

Why am I not getting the output of `id` executed by root?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use setuid and setgid to run a shell script as a different user. It's a security feature, and you can read more about it [in the very comprehensive top answer to this UL post.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts)

Comment: The script is not setuid or setgid, it is being invoked by an executable that is.

Comment: Ah, I would guess it's still much the same since it's still a shell script being called since this would be a simple way to circumvent the protection against it being done directly, but I can't say that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

aquote from the MAN page for `setuid()`

Thus, a set-user-ID-root program wishing to temporarily drop root priv‐
       ileges, assume the identity of an unprivileged user,  and  then  regain
       root privileges afterward cannot use setuid().  You can accomplish this
       with seteuid(2).

On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and  errno  is
       set appropriately.

```
   Note:  there  are cases where setuid() can fail even when the caller is
   UID 0; it is a grave security error to  omit  checking  for  a  failure
   return from setuid().
```

amongst other things, This means a user cannot become `root` via this command.

If the posted code had checked the returned value from these commands, the would have seen that the commands failed.